# MSAccess VBA: Pass values from a subform to a seperate form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form *frmDetail* that contains several locked fields I want populated only when another form has been filled out, in the name of having some kind of standardization in my data. This other form *frmSignOut* is used to enter in a date and location that will populate the fields on *frmDetail*. *frmSignOut* also contains a subform *subULookup* that looks up users from a different table using an identifier number. The resulting last name, first name and phone # should also be passed to *frmDetail*. I also hope to combine first and last name somehow into a Last,First format.

My approach so far has been to open *frmSignOut* modally with **acDialog** and I inserted **Visible=False** into the On_Click event on *frmSignOut*. Then I try to reference my subform fields and set them to the desired fields on *frmDetail*. I finish by refreshing and then closing the dialog form.

```
Private Sub CmdSignOut_Click()

DoCmd.OpenForm("frmSignOut"),,,,,acDialog
If CurrentProject.AllForms("frmSignOut").isLoaded=True Then
    Set Forms!frmSignOut!SubULookup.PhoneNbrTxt=Me.ContactNbrTxt
    DoCmd.Close (acForm), ("frmSignOut")
    Me.Refresh
  End If

End Sub
```

I have only been able to get this far, trying to pull the first field *PhoneNbrTxt*. I can get *frmSignOut* to open, I put in data and when I click my 'close' command button I get run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method.

The line highlighted is where I try to reference my subform field. I also have a 'Cancel' button added to *frmSignOut* that just closes the form, I have no errors there.

Again I'm completely new to Access without much prior experience in anything related, I'd appreciate any knowledge you guys can throw at me.

EDIT: I've been able to successfully pull the value to Me.ContactNbrTxt by adjusting my code to the below.

```
Me.ContactNbrTxt = Forms!FrmSignOut!SubULookup.Form!PhoneNbrTxt
```

It looks like the missing part was the *Form!* right before the control name, along with formatting this correctly and dropping *Set*.

Im still trying to work out how to combine first and last name before also pulling those to *frmDetail*, if anyone can help there.

Comment: Don't use `Set` just for populating a data control or field - remove that word. Are you duplicating data in multiple tables?

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear, the Me.ContactNbrText is on frmDetail, the form I want the data to end up on. Do I have this backwards? So should I drop 'Set' and start with Me.ContactNbrTxt? EDIT: I've made these changes and still receive the error 438

Comment: See you got it working. `.Form` isn't always required but can't hurt. You can concatenate fields to get `first, last`. But why?

Comment: There is only one field on frmDetail for 'Name'. I could just make another field but that value is also tied into a search function on another form that I do not want to change. To concatenate would I need get into defining the values as Strings or something similar? I have no experience there.

Comment: You say you have a users table so why are you also saving user info into another table? This defeats a major concept of relational database which is to not duplicate data. All you need in frmDetail (and its underlaying table) is user ID.

Comment: The main table is used to track media, the function I am working on now is to record who has signed out an item. As I understand it I would need to duplicate either user IDs or names, and names make it simpler to work into my search form. Is there a better way? And in case it helps, it might be important to know that most items wont be associated to a user most of the time.

Comment: Combobox can be set up so user sees and types names but code uses and saves ID. Names are very poor key values. This is what primary/foreign key fields are for. Only primary key is saved as foreign key into dependent table. Related info is retrieved in queries. Might look at MS Access Lending Library database template.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll take a look at the Lending Library Template. For what it's worth, I am using User IDs as the primary key and they are used to look up names/phone numbers using the SubUlookup subform.

Comment: That's great, just don't need to save the name/phone. And really, DLookup would be my last resort. Combobox can have ID, name parts and phone info as columns. Then expression in textbox can reference those columns by index to retrieve info for display.